# Is there a better way to write a "string contains X" method?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

Just stared using Haskell and realized (at far as I can tell) there is no direct way to check a string to see if it contains a smaller string.  So I figured I'd just take a shot at it.

Essentially the idea was to check if the two strings were the same size and were equal.  If the string being checked was longer, recursively lop of the head and run the check again until the string being checked was the same length.

The rest of the possibilities I used pattern matching to handle them.  This is what I came up with:

```
stringExists "" wordToCheckAgainst = False
stringExists wordToCheckFor "" = False
stringExists wordToCheckFor wordToCheckAgainst | length wordToCheckAgainst < length wordToCheckFor = False
                                               | length wordToCheckAgainst == length wordToCheckFor = wordToCheckAgainst == wordToCheckFor
                                               | take (length wordToCheckFor) wordToCheckAgainst == wordToCheckFor = True
                                               | otherwise = stringExists wordToCheckFor (tail wordToCheckAgainst)
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you search [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for the signature of the function you're looking for (`String -> String -> Bool`) you should see [`isInfixOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:isInfixOf) among the top results.

Comment: Examining [the source of `isInfixOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#isInfixOf) is instructive.

Comment: @dave4420 Link is broken.

Comment: [Un-borked link to source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#isInfixOf)

Comment: here's the source: `isInfixOf needle haystack = any (isPrefixOf needle) (tails haystack)`

Answer (score 25):

[`isInfixOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isInfixOf) from `Data.List` will surely solve the problem, however in case of longer haystacks or perverse¹ needles you should consider more advanced [string matching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) with a much better average and worst case complexity.

---

¹ Consider a really long string consisting only of `a`'s and a needle with a lot of `a`'s at the beginning and one `b` at the end.

Comment: Note that any more efficient algorithm would require a different data structure than `String` (or `[a]`).

Comment: Indeed, they usually need some initial preprocessing of the input string . Implementing them in a way resulting in a `(String -> String -> Bool)` function is absolutely possible, though.

Comment: If you're really interested in performance, you'd probably implement it like this: [Data.Text.Search.indices](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Text-Search.html#indices) (note `Data.Text.isInfixOf` is implemented in terms of this; due to laziness it can stop after the first index is found)

Answer (score 11):

Consider using the [`text` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text)(`text` on Hackage, now also part of Haskell Platform) for your text-processing needs. It provides a Unicode text type, which is more time- and space-efficient than the built-in list-based `String`. For string search, the `text` package [implements](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/src/Data.Text.Internal.Search.html) a [Boyer-Moore-based algorithm](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm), which has better complexity than the naïve method used by `Data.List.isInfixOf`.

Usage example:

```
Prelude> :s -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> import qualified Data.Text as T
Prelude Data.Text> T.breakOnAll "abc" "defabcged"
[("def","abcged")]
Prelude Data.Text> T.isInfixOf "abc" "defabcged"
True
```

Comment: Needing OverloadedStrings just to check for substring matches is a pretty nasty wart though. The alternative of having to wrap in `pack` and `unpack` is really unsatisfactory as well.